# deviceorientation events not working on Firefox desktop

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, device-orientation

I have a project in three.js with a webgl 360 panorama. I'm showing the panorama in browsers that support deviceorientation and webgl, and just showing a static image for browsers that don't support them.
But I have this problem with Firefox (v 43.0).
If I check deviceorientation support with Modernizr

```
Modernizr.deviceorientation
```

it returns true, but if I try

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', setControls, true);
```

the event is never called (only on Firefox).

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently on desktop, Firefox doesn't fire that event.